# Self-adjointness of a positive symmetric closed densely-defined operator $L:D\to H$ on a Hilbert space and domain of resolvent

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, spectral-theory

The following is Exercise 9.iii on a [write-up](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2011/12/20/the-spectral-theorem-and-its-converses-for-unbounded-symmetric-operators/) by Terence Tao, which I have been unable to fully crack:

> Let $H$ be a (complex) Hilbert space with dense subspace $D$. Let $L:D\to H$ be a symmetric closed positive operator, and let $w\in\Bbb C\setminus\Bbb R_{\ge0}$. Then the resolvent $R(w)$ is defined on all of $H$ (i.e. $L-wI$ is surjective) if and only if $L$ is self adjoint.

Now, it is relatively straightforward to prove that the resolvent $R(w)$ exists for $L$, and the condition of $L$ being self-adjoint is equivalent to requiring that for any $g\in H$, if the functional $$D\to\Bbb C, \quad f\mapsto\langle Lf,g\rangle$$ is bounded, then $g\in D$.

However, no amount of finicky manipulation seems to get me closer to a proof that this is equivalent to $L-w$ being surjective.